# Recursive %in% function in R?

Tags: r, recursion, pattern-matching

I am sure this is a simple question that has been asked many times, but this is one of those times when I find it difficult to know *which* terms to search for in order to find the solution. I have a simple list of lists, such as the one below:

```
sets <- list(S1=NA, S2=1L, S3=2:5)

> sets
$S1
[1] NA

$S2
[1] 1

$S3
[1] 2 3 4 5
```

And I have a scalar variable `val` which can take the value of any integer in `sets` (but will never be `NA`). Suppose `val <- 4` -- then, what is a quick way to return a vector of TRUE/FALSE corresponding to each list in `set` where TRUE means `val` is in that list and FALSE means it is not? In this case I would want something like

```
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

I was hoping there would be some recursive form of `%in%` but I haven't had luck searching for it. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
sapply(sets, `%in%`, x = val)
#    S1    S2    S3 
# FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

I had to look at the help page `?"%in%"` to find out that the first argument to `%in%` is named `x`. And for your curiosity (not needed here), the second one is named `table`.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about a named argument to `%in%`.

Comment: @flodel D'oh! I shoulda known. Thanks for that!